# Rebuilding RAID 5 in HP Proliant ML 370 G5 Server

Tags: hp, raid5

One of our customer having HP Proliant ML370 G5 server with Windows 2003 SBS.That having 2*72GB(Single Port10K Serial SCSI) and 3*146GB(Dual port10K SAS) harddisks.Now that is going to full.I want to extend the current RAID with two additional HDD(Either **146 SAS** or **300GB SAS**).Is this possible or not?**How I can rebuild the current RAID 5** without lossing any Data.Can you please tell me the steps for that???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extend Raid5 with a new HD (HP DL380 G3)](http://serverfault.com/questions/20815/extend-raid5-with-a-new-hd-hp-dl380-g3)

Answer (score 1):

First, Backup.

Second, Verify Backup, then backup again.

I'm assuming that your current config is that the 2x72GB are a RAID1 array, and the 3x146GB disks are the RAID5 array, and that any new disks will be added to one of the empty drive bays.

I believe that this is answered here:
[Extend Raid5 with a new HD (HP DL380 G3)](https://serverfault.com/questions/20815/extend-raid5-with-a-new-hd-hp-dl380-g3)
(the HP software and hardware is

I think it may be possible doing it online using the HP Array Configuration Utility from within Windows (You do have the HP PSP installed, right?), I believe that you can add disks to a RAID5 array and set it to add the disk to the array.

Ensure that the server is on backup power and that there's no possiblity of Updates or a reboot happening; That would really break your filesystem in the middle of a rebuild.